# Bypassing double quote in DOM based XSS?

Tags: xss, exploit, dom

I am trying to generate a POC for DOM XSS exploit. I could inject a code using the following link:

```
<a href="wepage.jsp" target='&quot;><script> alert(document.cookie)</script></div>'>domxss</a>
```

The injected code appears in a `div` element in the `data-window` parameter:

```
<div id="23212" class="contextMenu" data-window="&quot;><script> alert(document.cookie)</script></div>" style="display: none;"><a .....
```

I tried to pass `&quote` as a hex code, double encoded (`%2522`), with hackbar `String.fromCharCode...`, but still the double quote is rendered back to `&quote;`

Any hint for how to bypass the double quote or if there is another way to inject alert here?

Comment: Do you know anything about the process by which the payload ends up in the `data-window` attribute?

Comment: What if you just pass in the hex code for a double quote? since it seems to be translating your HTML entities perfectly fine.

Comment: does the injection appear in view-source?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.

If you see `"` getting transformed to `&quot;` as it passes through the HTML, then that usually means that the application is doing output escaping properly.